# .NET TCP socket with session

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Is there any way of dealing with sessions with sockets in C#?

Example of my problem:
I have a server with a socket listening on port 5672.

```
TcpListener socket = new TcpListener(localAddr, 5672);  
socket.Start();  
Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");  

// Perform a blocking call to accept requests.  
TcpClient client = socket.AcceptTcpClient();  
Console.WriteLine("Connected to client!");
```

And i have two clients that will send one byte. Client A send 0x1 and client B send 0x2.
From the server side, i read this data like this:

```
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
String data = null;

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
while ((stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
{
     byte[] answer = new ...
     stream.Write(answer , 0, answer.Length);
}
```

Then client A sends 0x11.
I need a way to know that this client is the same that sent "0x1" before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `TcpClient` instance is for a different connection. A connection in TCP consists of four things: source IP, source port, target IP, target port. So, even if you have the same target IP and port, and the same source port, you have two different connections.

Data sent by one client will not be mixed in with data sent by the other client. Data sent by a client on a connection will be received in order over that connection.

The only time that Sessions become an issue is to remember the client after the connection is closed.

Comment: I did not understood how the data will not be mixed. After i read the data sent by first client, the TcpClient object is destroyed. And to read the following data i have to do socket.AcceptTcpClient(); again. Can you post a demo code that detects when client A sends 0x11 after sendig 0x1? Thanks

Comment: @ZeCarlos: do you really need to close the `TcpClient` instances? Why not reuse them? Each one would be able to get you an uncorrupted stream of data from exactly one client.

Comment: You're right. I can reuse TcpClient and its associated stream. Sorry for my ignorance. Thanks

Comment: @ZeCarlos: There's no reason to apologize for ignorance; only for not attempting to alleviate ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to implement your own protocol in order to identify the clients. Perhaps define a chunk of bytes, where in addition to the data you also include a client identifier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i can't do that. I'm implementing a protocol that communicates over TCP. I cannot modify the information sent by clients.

Comment: @ZeCarlos: so who defines the format of the data sent by the clients?

Comment: Its an protocol. AMQP it this case. http://www.amqp.org/confluence/download/attachments/720900/amqp0-9.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1183135701000 
But the data in frames doesn't have any field identifing the client. I identification as to be done by knowing the ip and port used by client side. I'm looking for some way which this is done automaticaly

Comment: I think you're going to need some sort of transport layer encryption then. I still don't know nearly enough about your needs to suggest something good here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some sort of authentication or pre-negotiated token, and all of this somehow encrypted with some salt.

Comment: You certainly wouldn't need any salted hashes or encryption for the means of identification, however depending on the particular needs it might be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of existing literature on how sessions are implemented in the Web world (HTTP).

One key is whether you are closing the client connections, or are they persistent? If they are persistent, then simply identify them by their object reference. If not, then...

1) You can do simple sessions based on the source IP address. But if multiple clients are behind a NAT firewall, sharing the IP, then that doesn't work, see the next option.

2) Use a "cookie"

3) Use authentication to identify each client

Every option except IP based sessions requires adding something to the protocol itself.

Some things to remember with sockets. The remote IP + remote port uniquely identifies a client TCP socket. Multiple connections from the same remote client will have diffent remote ports. But you cannot rely on that if the socket closes, because the remote OS may recycle the remote port for a new connection once the old one times out.